# How to attach String in jsp test attribute

Tags: java, jsp

In the following Code, `page.currentPagePath` is for example `www.index` and  `value.path` is `www.index.html`. I would like to check if both are not equals

```
<c:if test="${page.currentPagePath '.html' ne value.path} }">
                                    <li class="main-nav">                                            
                                        <a class="main-nav-link"
                                           href="${value.redirectPath}">${value.pageTitle}</a>
                                    </li>
                                    </c:if>
```

How can I attach `.html` to `page.currentPagePath` in the test? `page.currentPagePath '.html'` did not work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The concatenator operator is the same as in Java : `+`:

```
${(page.currentPagePath + '.html') ne value.path}
```